# How i can set Toast message text from xml file

Tags: android

Is there any way I can set `toast` text from `.xml`file?

for example :

```
 Toast.makeText(SmsManager.this,android.R.string.toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Create a String named as `toast_text` in `string.xml`. ANd use `Toast.makeText(SmsManager.this,R.string.toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course !

If stored in the strings.xml, you can use `R.string.your_text`